# Try catch not working even when error is occuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch

I have some code which executes on the submission of a form.
It posts to an API route.

```
  handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/project`, {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: this.state.name,
          description: this.state.description
        }),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      });
      return response ? response.json() : response;
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
    }
  };
```

The problem is when testing this I change the API route to a deliberately invalid route in order to cause an error. However the catch code is not getting hit.
Have I setup the try-catch wrong?

Comment: Have you tried checking out the network traffic to see what you get back? A 404 I don't beleive will be considered an exception, it would just be a response you need to check for for instance

Comment: Yes I get back a 404: so what would be considered an exception?

Comment: An exception is a specific object that gets created based on code that did not run as expected. A 404 is not unexpected in the code, so essentially what you need to do is check the response status code and see if it equals 404, then handle how wish from there. You may want to include other statuses in there too, something like a 200 might be the only valid response for instance

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is that receiving a 404 is not an exception. To handle this, you should add some code that will check the status code of the response and from there determine what should be done. For example you would receive the response and use the following:

```
if(response.status == 404)
    //Code for not receiving the content you expect
```

The issue is there are a lot of potential responses you may get back that will not be what you are looking for, so I would actually recommend whitelisting particular response ranges instead of looking for ones that are a problem. For example

```
if(response.status >= 200 && response.status <= 299)
    //Code to run when you receieve a good response
```

This is an example, it will be up to you to determine what are the responses you wish to handle.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` only raises an error if there was an error making or receiving the response. A HTTP 404 should be treated as a "successful" response and is up to the user to decide what to do with such response.

If you want to reject non-20x responses and you already have a business logic to handle error on your `catch` code, you can throw a new Error and handle it alongside another errors:

```
try {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/project`, {
    ...
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response.json()
    } else {
        var error = new Error(response.statusText || response.status)
        error.response = response
        throw(error)
    }
} catch (error) {
   console.log(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need fetch specific error you have to follow below way:

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    fetch(`${API_URL}/project`, {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: this.state.name,
            description: this.state.description
        }),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    }).then((response) => {
        return response ? response.json() : response;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(`fetch specific error: ${error}`)
    });
};
```